# Chrome App receive (TCP) data from network example fails

Tags: google-chrome, tcp, google-chrome-app

I can't make it work with a Chrome App to receive data over TCP connection from the server. I get no onReceived event. It works only the second time, but not the first. I copied everything from the docs but the code just doesn't work and I have no idea what is wrong. I can see my 'ABCDEFGHI' string being sent by the server in the tcpdump window but for some reason Chrome doesn't get it. The error in this example is fully reproducible. Here are the files:

THE APP

```
[niko@dev1 nettest]$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 niko niko 174 Aug  6 16:10 background.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 niko niko 208 Aug  6 16:11 main.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 niko niko 928 Aug  6 16:54 main.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 niko niko 281 Aug  6 16:10 manifest.json
[niko@dev1 nettest]$
```

manifest.json:

```
[niko@dev1 nettest]$ cat manifest.json 
{
  "name": "Receive Test",
  "description": "Network receive test App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { 
    },

    "sockets": {
        "tcp" : {
              "connect": ["*"]
        }
    }
}
[niko@dev1 nettest]$
```

background.js:

```
[niko@dev1 nettest]$ cat background.js 
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
[niko@dev1 nettest]$
```

main.html:

```
[niko@dev1 nettest]$ cat main.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Networking test app</div>
    <a href="" id="connect_btn">conect</a>
  </body>
</html>

[niko@dev1 nettest]$
```

main.js:

```
[niko@dev1 nettest]$ cat main.js 
var socket;
window.addEventListener("load",init);
function init() {
    var el;
    el=document.getElementById('connect_btn');
    if (el!=null) el.addEventListener("click",connect_click);
}
function connect_click(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, function(createInfo) {
        socket=createInfo.socketId;
        chrome.sockets.tcp.setPaused(socket, false);
        chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socket,"localhost", 4433, connect_callback);
    });
}
function connect_callback(info) {

    console.log("connection accepted: "+info);
    chrome.sockets.tcp.setPaused(socket, false);
    chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener(receive_error);
    chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(data_received);

}
function data_received(info) {
    console.log("the data has been received:");
    console.log(info);
}   
function receive_error(info) {
    console.log("receive error");
    console.log(info);
}

[niko@dev1 nettest]$
```

SERVER CODE:

```
[niko@dev1 src]$ cat server.c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flag=1;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char data[10] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','\n'};
    int result;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    result = setsockopt(listenfd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,(char *) &flag, sizeof(int)); 
    if (result<0) {
        printf("result=%d\n",result);
        return (1);
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(4433); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
        result = setsockopt(connfd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,(char *) &flag, sizeof(int)); 
        if (result<0) {
            printf("result=%d\n",result);
            return (1);
        }
        printf("connection accepted, sending data\n");
        write(connfd, &data, sizeof(data)); 
        sleep(5);

        close(connfd);
        printf("connection closed\n");
        sleep(1);
     }
}
[niko@dev1 src]$
```

When I run the code this is the output:

```
connection accepted: 0
main.js:31 receive error
main.js:32 Object {resultCode: -100, socketId: 18}
main.js:20 connection accepted: 0
main.js:27 the data has been received:
main.js:28 Object {data: ArrayBuffer, socketId: 19}
main.js:27 the data has been received:
main.js:28 Object {data: ArrayBuffer, socketId: 19}
main.js:31 receive error
main.js:32 Object {resultCode: -100, socketId: 19}
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: I found that adding a sleep(1) after accept() syscall on the server.c it works. However, this is not usable for me, thats a lot of time wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. onReceived handler must be registered immediately after socket creation. Otherwise, what happens is : client sends SYN, but the server replies with ACK + data. When Chrome gets this packet it doesn't yet have onReceived handler set so data in the first packet is lost. connect_click() function must be rewritten like this:

```
function connect_click(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, function(createInfo) {
        socket=createInfo.socketId;
        chrome.sockets.tcp.setPaused(socket, false );
        chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socket,"localhost", 4433, connect_callback);
        chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(data_received);
        chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener(receive_error);
    });
}
```